# MS SQL Store Procedure to display concatenated values from different cells

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is it possible to convert below current table into the target view using Stored procedure or View , ID is unique here and each ID may contain different type of accounts and each type can have more than 1 number.
can anyone help ?

Current table

```
ID  Type    Account Balance
1   checking    11111   100
1   checking    22222   200
1   savings 33333   300
1   savings 4444    400
2   investment  55555   500
2   checking    66666   600
```

Target

```
ID  Key Value
1   Checking1_Account   11111
1   Checking2_Account   22222
1   Checking1_Balance   100
1   Checking2_Balance   200
1   Savings1_Account    33333
1   Savings2_Account    44444
1   Savings1_Balance    300
1   Savings2_Balance    400
2   Investment1_Account 55555
2   Investment1_Balance 500
2   Checking1_Account   66666
2   Checking1_Balance   600
```

Comment: which database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for sql-server 2008

```
select * 
into #tempt
from 
(values (1,   'checking',    '11111',   100),
 (1,   'checking',    22222,   200),
(1,   'savings', 33333  , 300),
(1,   'savings', 4444  ,  400),
(2,   'investment', 55555 ,  500),
(2,   'checking',   66666 ,  600)
) x (ID,  Type,    Account, Balance)



select ID,Type + cast(row_number() over (partition by ID,Type Order by Account) as varchar(5)) + '_Account' [Key],Account [Value] from #tempt
union
select ID,Type +  cast(row_number() over (partition by ID,Type Order by Account) as varchar(5)) + '_Balance' [Key],Account [Value] from #tempt    order by id, [key]



drop table #tempt




(6 row(s) affected)
ID          Key                                        Value
----------- ------------------------------------------ -----------
1           checking1_Account                          11111
1           checking1_Balance                          100
1           checking2_Account                          22222
1           checking2_Balance                          200
1           savings1_Account                           4444
1           savings1_Balance                           400
1           savings2_Account                           33333
1           savings2_Balance                           300
2           checking1_Account                          66666
2           checking1_Balance                          600
2           investment1_Account                        55555
2           investment1_Balance                        500
```

Comment: can you help with SQL 2008 compatible one pls ?

Answer (score 2):

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
    Select *,RN   = Row_Number() over (Partition By ID,Type Order by Account)
     From  YourTable
)
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  cte A
 Cross Apply (values (concat(A.[Type],A.RN,'_Account'),A.Account)
                    ,(concat(A.[Type],A.RN,'_Balance'),A.Balance)
             ) B ([Key],Value)
```

**Returns**

[image]

> **EDIT 2008 Compatible**

```
;with cte as (
    Select *,RN   = Row_Number() over (Partition By ID,Type Order by Account)
     From  YourTable
)
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  cte A
 Cross Apply (values (A.[Type]+cast(A.RN as varchar(25))+'_Account',A.Account)
                    ,(A.[Type]+cast(A.RN as varchar(25))+'_Balance',A.Balance)
             ) B ([Key],Value)
```

Comment: , looks like concat is not supported in SQL 2008 , so I replaced with fn CONCAT like this

Comment: concat is not supported in SQL 2008,I replaced with fn CONCAT which supports only 2 strings to be concatenated so I used fn contact twice like this , getting error "The data types varchar and bigint are incompatible in the concat operator"
;with cte as (
    Select *,RN   = Row_Number() over (Partition By ID,Type Order by Account)
     From  YourTable
)
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  cte A
 Cross Apply (values ({fn concat({fn concat(A.[Type],A.RN)},'_Account')},A.Account)
                    ,({fn concat({fn concat(A.[Type],A.RN)},'_Balance')},A.Balance)
             ) B ([Key],Value)

Comment: @AHS One moment and I will make it 2008 compatible

Comment: Regardless of plan, this code doesn't repeat itself (the `ROW_NUMBER()`) and so is more maintainable.

Comment: Is it possible to convert the above result from rows to column , example all the values under Key as columns names example Checking1_Account , Checking1_Balance and as column names and all the values from 'Value' columns as it's values in one single row ?